# Wordpress URL rewrite if current page is using a single.php

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

Ok so i've been looking around alot lately the past 3 days and I can't figure this out..

Heres what the problem is and what I need to solution to end up like..

Problem -
  I'm using Wordpress as a CMS, mostly everything is set up as pages using custom templates. 
I have a page called Blog which is using a template that calls all the posts I've written minus the custom post types. It lists all those perfectly find like any normal blog. Even when I click on a post, it still works and redirects to the post using the single.php template file.
But the URL goes from A to B after clicking on a post.

A(before click) : http://www.mysite.com/blog
to
B(after post click) : http://www.mysite.com/this-is-my-post

I've tried messing with permalinks but nothing works correctly the way I need it.

Solution:
   I need the finalized URL to output like so http://www.mysite.com/blog/this-is-my-post

How do I rewrite the URLs to be like so if i'm using a custom page template for the blog?

thanks for the help, this is making my brain hurt ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Permalinks and select the "Custom Structure" option in the radio buttons. Then enter "/blog/%postname%/" as the value.

Comment: already tried this and since im using a custom post-type, on those specific pages it adds in /blog/route/tomy/custom/posttype to the url and I need those to have just mysite.com/route/tomy/custom/posttype without the extra added /blog/ in there.. everything else on the page works fine except for the single custom post type template.